# Is $\mathrm{gnu}(2304)$ known?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

(Here, $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ denotes the number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism.)

I wonder whether the number of groups of order $2304=2^8\times 3^2$ is known. GAP exited because of the memory. $\mathrm{gnu}(2304)$ must be greater than $1,000,000$ because of $\mathrm{gnu}(768)=1,090,235$ and $768=2^8\times 3|2^8\times 3^2=2304$.

> Is $\mathrm{gnu}(2304)$ known or at least a tight upper bound?
>
> What is the smallest number $n$, such that it is infeasible to calculate $\mathrm{gnu}(n)\ ?$ I think, $\mathrm{gnu}(2048)$ will be known in at most ten years, probably much earlier.
>
> Could $n=3072=2^{10}\times 3$ be the smallest too difficult case ?

Comment: According to Maple, $\operatorname{gnu}( 2304 ) = 15756130$. However, Maple does not know $\operatorname{gnu}( 3072 )$.

Comment: @James: I believe that Maple draws this number from [The construction of finite solvable groups revisited](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4239) by Bettina Eick and Max Horn. Thus, the answer to the first of the several questions asked here is YES. See also [the slides "Solvable Group Generation"](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/ws-qac/slides/Horn.pdf)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Yes, I checked and that is indeed the source for that particular value.

Comment: $\operatorname{gnu}(2048)$ would be known within ten years (that is, before Jan 3 2026)? Well, I would't be so optimistic here ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are indeed $112\,184+1\,953+15\,641 993 = 15\,756\,130$ groups of order 2304, computed using an algorithm developed by Bettina Eick and myself. As Alexander Konovalov already kindly pointed out, you can find this number in our paper "*The construction of finite solvable groups revisited*", J. Algebra 408 (2014), 166–182, also [available on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4239).

This is part of an on-going project to catalogue all groups up to order 10,000 (with a few orders excepted, e.g. multiples of 1024, as there are simply to many of these). So in particular, we skip groups of order 3072. There are already $49\,487\,367\,289$ groups of order 1024, and I expect the number of groups of order 3072 to be several orders of magnitude larger.

To maybe slightly motivate why I think so, consider this the proportion of number of (isomorphism clases of) groups of order $2^n$ vs $3\cdot 2^n$, computed here using GAP:

```
gap> List([0..9], n -> NrSmallGroups(3*2^n)/NrSmallGroups(2^n)*1.0);
[ 1., 2., 2.5, 3., 3.71429, 4.52941, 5.77903, 8.66366, 19.4366, 38.9397 ]
```

If you plot $n$ against $gnu(3\cdot 2^n)/gnu(2^n)$, you'll see a roughly exponentially looking curve. Of course that is a purely empiric argument, not a proof of anything.

Comment: why is the number you've stated (15755894) different from 15756130 given in http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4239 ?

Comment: Oops, because I copied the answer from my own slides (the ones you gave a link to already, in fact), but these contain a mistake in the computation of the sum (i.e. very, very basic and stupid). I should have looked at the paper, were we of course double checked evertything. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me.