# Number of groups of order $9261$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

I checked the odd numbers upto $10\ 000$ , whether they are group-perfect ($gnu(n)=n$ , where $gnu(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$), and
the only case I could not decide is

$$9261=3^3\times 7^3$$

> What is $gnu(9261)=gnu(3^3\times 7^3)$ ?

I would already be content with a proof of $gnu(9261)<9261$, which is my
conjecture because $gnu(3087)=46$ is small and $9261=3\times 3087$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599437/8581

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's not truet. Any finite group of order divisible by $p^k$ for $p$ prime has a subgroup of that order. In particular, a group of order $27$ has a subgroup of order $9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORRECTION: There are $215$ groups of order 9261 (by the same methods as used for previous questions).

As was pointed out by @James the `ConstrucctAllGroups` may return lists that are not yet isomorphism tested.

In this case there is one list, and a hard isomorphism test distinguishes the two groups.

```
m:=Filtered(l,IsList);
IsomorphismGroups(m[1][1],m[1][2]); #returns fail
```

Comment: Interesting - see the new answer by @James claiming it is 215

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is $\operatorname{gnu}( 9261 ) = 215$. By itself, the grpconst package function [`ConstructAllGroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grpconst/htm/CHAP003.htm) may produce a list in which not all groups have been distinguished up to isomorphism. Thus it is not sufficient to simply count the number of elements of the list it returns.  One must also check whether there are any nested lists consisting of groups whose isomorphism has not been decided by the algorithm.  The GrpConst package then provides the function [`DistinguishGroups`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grpconst/htm/CHAP004.htm#SECT004) that employs stronger methods to resolve any undecided isomorphisms remaining.

Here is a simplified version of the frontend that I use that employs these considerations.

```
CountGroups := function( n )
  local L, trouble, okay, c;

  L := ConstructAllGroups( n );
  okay := Filtered( L, x -> not IsList( x ) );
  trouble := Filtered( L, IsList );

  if Length( trouble ) > 0 then
    for c in trouble do
      c := DistinguishGroups( c, true );
      if ForAny( c, IsList ) then
        Error( "could not resolve some isomorphisms" );
      fi;
      Append( okay, c );
    od;
  fi;

  return Length( okay );
end;;
```

Using this, we obtain the claimed result.

```
gap> CountGroups( 9261 );
215
```

Having said all that, I confess I am far from an expert on GAP. If I have made a mistake, I should be happy to improve my understanding.

Comment: Looks correct to me - I think the answer is likely most likely right (I did not rerun it). Thanks for drawing attention to the documentation as well ;-) indeed, it says that it may return lists.

Comment: It would be very disappointing if GAP might made an error with the ConstructOfAllGroups-command. I was sure the command is reliable.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thanks for your comment, and for improving my answer formatting.

Comment: @Peter Please note that my answer does not suggest any error in the ConstructAllGroups command, but rather with how it is used.

Comment: @James But almost every user would expect that the groups are checked rigorously for isomorphism.

Comment: @Peter I agree, but ... RTFM? :-)  The first paragraph of documentation for this function fairly clearly describes its behaviour. I'm sure the package authors had their reasons for making this design choice. (See, for example, p. 9 of the manual.)

Comment: @Peter: perhaps one should re-check all your recent questions where `ConstructAllGroups` was used to calculate the answer in case it happened to return a list with sublist(s). I've already expressed some suggestions for a collaborative project to run a server with known $gnu(n)$ - see them in my comments at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1601470/. That would be more efficient than MSE for such a project, but so far nobody wrote to me.

Comment: I would help to create tables, but unfortunately, I am totally dependent on GAP. It seems too difficult to create a rigorous independent algorithm.

Comment: @Peter: One last time: I do not imply that you will write any new GAP code, though you are certainly very welcome to do so. But creating an issue for a particular $gnu(n)$ on GitHub will give full control when to close it (unlike here where upvotes of the answer remove the question from the list of unaswereds), will allow to link to other issues and commits in the GAP repository, and will be visible by more GAP developers. It would be perfectly fine to create an issue for a tricky order on GitHUb, while I doubt that asking new questions for particular values of $gnu(n)$ will run well here.

Comment: P.S. @Peter (last comment used all 500 chars): also, there is help with testing and documenting things

Comment: I've been running @James function and it works fine. Great job !!!!

Answer (score 1):

@james was right, please do not take my answer as a correct answer.
It seems that *gnu(9261)=215*

Comment: Thanks for approving the result. How long did the calculation take ?

Comment: It takes about 5 hours with an intel core i7, 128 GB RAM 2800Mhz

Comment: Thanks that you took the time although the result was already mentioned.

Comment: @AngelBlasco thanks - good to cross-check! Same number using two different methods.

Comment: @AngelBlasco oops - please read all further findings above and note `ConstructAllGroups ` specification. Could you please correct the answer?

Comment: Can I at least rely on the NrSmallGroup-command ?

Comment: And what about the NumberCFGroup-command with the cubefree-package ?

Comment: It is not posible, argument in NumberCFGroups function must be a cube-free integer