# For which $n$ in $2048 < n < 4096$ is the exact number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism currently unknown?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

The number of groups of order $2^{11} = 2048$ up to isomorphism is currently unknown, that is at least, as of 2023. The same can be said of $2^{12}=2 \cdot 2048 = 4096$. What about the number of groups of order $n$ for $2048 < n < 4096$?

Perhaps for example $3072 = 1024 \cdot 3 = 2^{10} \cdot 3$, as it has the same number of prime factors (with multiplicity) as $2048$? Or is this one known?

Comment: Here you can find at least a criteria for orders of $n$ for which the number of groups is known: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_given_order

Comment: It is a very long time ago I dealt with groups , but if I remember it right , $3072$ is a hot candidate for an unsolved case.

Comment: For a list of the orders that are not currently in the SmallGroups database, go to 
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ and run "for n in [2049..4095] do
if NumberOfSmallGroups(n) eq 0 then
n;
end if;
end for;"
One could argue this is a candiate list for "unknown" orders. Of course, not all these orders are equally difficult, and some of them could be done without too much effort (for example, I am aware of an algorithm currently being implemented to deal with cubefree orders).

Comment: A more complete query can be done via https://groups.quendi.de, e.g. https://groups.quendi.de/?order_min=2049&order_max=4095 for the given range.  Or use GAP https://www.gap-system.org which is free and open source. The cubefree orders up to 50000 are also already all in GAP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tl;dr: the only "unknown" order is 3072.

In the [small groups library](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/small/) (available in the computer algebra systems [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org) and [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/)), many of the groups of order in the range from 2049 to 4095 are already available. Indeed, all but 216 of them. Here is a check in GAP that counts how many orders are *missing*

```
gap> Length(Filtered([2049..4095], n -> not SmallGroupsAvailable(n)));
216
```

The relatively new GAP package [SotGrps](https://gap-packages.github.io/sotgrps/) by Eileen Pan (as far as I know equivalent code is also in Magma) adds support for more infinite families of groups, but in this case, that just takes care of 2 of the "missing" orders.

However, using e.g. the [GrpConst package](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/grpconst.html) by Besche and Eick (with some minor optimizations by myself) plus enough patience and waiting time one can construct the groups of many of the missing orders. We did so as part of our paper

> *Eick, Bettina; Horn, Max; Hulpke, Alexander*, [**Constructing groups of ‘small’ order: recent results and open problems**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-70566-8_8), Böckle, Gebhard (ed.) et al., Algorithmic and experimental methods in algebra, geometry, and number theory. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-70565-1/hbk; 978-3-319-70566-8/ebook). 199-211 (2017). [ZBL1400.20014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1400.20014).

Now, this leaves some "hard" orders. In the end, just two are left, 2304 and 3072.

For the order $2304=2^8\cdot 3^2$, we were able to deal with it with a new algorithms presented in

> *Eick, Bettina; Horn, Max*, [**The construction of finite solvable groups revisited**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2013.09.028), J. Algebra 408 (2014), 166–182, also available on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4239).

This only leaves order $3072=2^{10}\cdot 3$, which is currently out of reach. To resolve it, we'd first have to actually compute all the groups of order 1024; we know how many there are up to isomorphism ($49\,487\,367\,289$) and in principle have the tools to compute them, it's a matter of patience (CPU time, and perhaps RAM size etc.).  But then you need to perform computations for each of these groups to get the "descendants" of order 3072. That would be a massive computations -- it might just be feasible if you have a big enough compute cluster and lots of time and write some improved code, but frankly, I am not sure it'd be worth the effort. That said, others might think the same about order 2304, so ....

You can browse a lot of the data we produced in our papers at https://groups.quendi.de.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: [Max Horn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12415/max-horn) has just posted a [better answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810738/602386) on this question with the same info as their posted comments on this answer as well as more details.

---

A **partial** answer to this question. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1599437/602386) by [Max Horn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12415/max-horn) who developed a certain algorithm to enumerate group orders writes

> This [the algorithm] is part of an on-going project to catalogue all groups up to order 10,000 (with a few orders excepted, e.g. multiples of 1024, as there are simply to many of these). So in particular, we skip groups of order 3072. There are already $49,487,367,289$ groups of order 1024, and I expect the number of groups of order 3072 to be several orders of magnitude larger.

The answer was posted in 2016 and I am struggling to find anything more recent (or any academic source, although as an undergraduate I'm not really experienced with that), so it seems that the number of groups of order $3072$ was unknown then in 2016 and is still unknown.

Other comments on that post also suggest that $3072$ is unknown.

Comment: Yes, 3072 is unknown. Computing it would require iterating over each of the $49\,487\,367\,289$ groups of order 1024 and computing among other things the automorphism groups of all. As a first step, we would have to compute *those* groups, though (we currently only have the number). I guess In principle it would be possible to do it with a big enough cluster and if one is willing to wait long enough, but honestly I don't think it'd be worthwhile.

Comment: This query also confirms that 3072 is the only number in the given range were we don't know the answer: https://groups.quendi.de/?order_min=2049&order_max=4095

Comment: As to an academic source, see also our paper "Constructing groups of ‘small’ order: Recent results and open problems" (joint with Bettina Eick and Alexander Hulpke), https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-70566-8_8

Comment: @MaxHorn Thank you very much - this completely answers my question. If you'd like to write an answer about this I'd happily accept it, otherwise I'll edit this answer of mine with the result and say "see comments below from Max Horn" :)